# Ant's exec returns an error on copy

Tags: java, ant, cmd, exec

I need to concatenate two files. I use Ant's exec for this purpose, but I get the following error.

```
production:
 [exec] Current OS is Windows 7
 [exec] Executing 'cmd' with arguments:
 [exec] 'copy /B destination\bin\installer.sh+destination.tar.gz Installer.bin'
 [exec]
 [exec] The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
 [exec] not part of the command.
 [exec] Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]
 [exec] Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
 [exec]
```

The task looks like this:

```
<target name="production" depends="tar" >
    <exec dir="${bin}"  executable="cmd">
        <arg line="'copy /B destination\bin\installer.sh+destination.tar.gz Installer.bin'"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

```
<target name="production" depends="tar" >
  <exec dir="${bin}" executable="cmd">
    <arg line="/C copy /B destination\bin\installer.sh+destination.tar.gz Installer.bin"/>
  </exec>
</target>
```

You would need to have the `/C` to indicate that you are passing a command in to the cmd.exe

Answer (score 3):

You could use the ant [concat](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/concat.html) task to do this more easily. Don't forget to set the `binary` flag. As a bonus this will work beyond Windows.